# Could the Marauder's Map show creatures whose feet don't touch the ground?

Tags: harry-potter, marauders-map, animagi

A potential loophole came to mind when thinking of an answer to [a question regarding Rita Skeeter and the Marauder's Map](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/169623/why-didnt-rita-skeeter-appear-on-the-marauders-map).

Rita is an animagus whose form is that of a beetle. She often uses this form to eavesdrop on others in her line of work, and would likely have used it in the school.  Beetles are known to typically have flight and enjoy clinging to walls.  The Marauder's Map shows the *footprints* of people on the school *grounds*.

Would it show, say, a wizard transformed into a beetle in flight or clinging on the wall? Does it show any airborne targets in the books or movies?

Comment: I believe Peeves shows up on the map, though I'd have to track down the quote.

Comment: The movies show footprints. The books just show dots, including animals. So, yes, presumably Rita and the owls would all be shown.

Comment: Iirc it also shows ghosts...

Comment: Does it show Dementors?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Yes, the map could detect people whose feet don't touch the ground. It detected Peeves, and he floated.

> Out in the dark corridor, Harry examined the Marauder’s Map to check that the coast was still clear. Yes, the **dots** belonging to Filch and his cat, Mrs. Norris, were safely in their office . . . nothing else seemed to be moving apart from **Peeves, though he was bouncing around the trophy room on the floor above**.
>
> *Goblet of Fire*

Comment: maybe his dot only appears when he touches the ground.... :P

Comment: Peeves is not a "people" though

Comment: @user13267 I know he is not a "people". I just used that as a generic term to include live humans, ghosts, and poltergeists. I guess the map would show other people too, such as goblins, elves, and centaurs.